# How to recognize user name who run script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

In order to use `chown` command I need to know who's running my script. Real name because it's going to be run with sudo. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `LOGNAME`or `USER` env variables.

Comment: Both variables with sudo output root, but $(logname) result is correct value

Comment: It's said that env vars are not reliable. And as far as i understand there is difference between `logname` and `id`. First gives you login name, and `id` gives the UID of invoking process, which could be different in SUID invocations, no?

Comment: @Yrgl: Use `SUDO_USER` under `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, there is also `id -un` and `whoami` but env vars should probably be preferred unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: $(id -un) and $(whoami) with sudo output root

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Init
FILE="/tmp/out.$$"
GREP="/bin/grep"
#....
# Make sure only root can run our script
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
exit 1
fi
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`id -run` gives you real UID, not effective one.

Comment: Bash outputs `id: cannot print only names or real IDs in default format`

Comment: No, it doesn't, at least in my case: `sudo id -run` → `root`